# Add project source control, incorrect folder

Tags: tfs, source-control-explorer

I'm having a problem with my source control.

I have a new project called CustomizedControllers, and I'm adding this project to my solution, but in TFS it's going to wrong directory, something like that:

**This is my local directories:**

```
STUFF
|-DOCUMENTS
|- | - Blah
|-SOLUTION
|- |- Project0
|- |- Project1
|- |- Project2
|- |- CustomizedControllers
```

**This is what happens when I try to add this new project to source control:**

```
STUFF
|-DOCUMENTS
|- | - Blah
|-NEWCRAZYCREATEDDIRECTORY
|- |- CustomizedControllers
|-SOLUTION
|- |- Project0
|- |- Project1
|- |- Project2
```

So, How can I add this new project to correct directory?

Comment: At what folder in your diagram is the sln file?

Answer (score 0):

As @MrHinsh said, it should create the project folder where your sln file is.  The easiest way around this I find is create the project independently and add it as an existing project to the solution.